Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler'
I am not able to create a bean with @Import(ExceptionHandler.class)
I am trying to use validations but the controller does not get the request and the postman simply returning 400 bad request whereas I had given my custom message to responseenter image description here

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
